# using img templats with ngSrc sends text/html instead of image/gif when data array is loaded via $http

Tags: image, http, angularjs

I have a template like this:

```
<img class="picto" 
    ng-repeat="module in modules" 
    ng-src="{{module.Source}}" 
    title="{{module.Title}}" 
    ng-click="module.handler();"/>
```

When I set the `$scope.modules` array using static code, everything works fine, and the images are fetched via GET using media type "image/gif" (for gif files). However, when I retrieve the same array using `$http.get()` - see the code below -, angular tries to retrieve the images using media type "text/html" which results in an 404 error:

```
$http.get('/api/modules', {})
    .success(function (data) {
        $http.defaults.get = { 'Content-Type': 'image/gif' }; // apparently useless
        $scope.modules = data;
        for (var module in $scope.modules) {
            $scope.modules[module].handler = function () { alert(this.Id); };
        }
        delete $http.defaults.get; // ...useless 
    });
```

Trying to add a header default did not help either (`// apparently useless`). Can you see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `Accept: 'image/gif'` instead of `Content-Type: 'image/gif'`.

The `Content-Type` header describes the data format you are sending to the server.  The `Accept` header describes the data formats you accept in response from the server.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. However, you gave me a hint telling me that this is a problem which does not relate to the media type. What I see in the browser trace log is the media type of the answer. Since the return code is 404 and the response contains an error message, "text/html" is correct type for the response. I mistakenly assumed that it showed the accepted media type header sent with the request.

Comment: The problem now appears not to be related to AngularJS but to the way requests are handled by ASP.Net MVC/WebAPI.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Well I can't help you there, but I am glad this helped zero in on the issue.